# Trouble with Delete

Tags: javascript, express

I'm not sure why I keep getting this message(below). I'm trying to delete an entry but I keep let the Error Message below. I need an experts help.

```
//Error Message
Cannot DELETE /pokies/Spearowhj  

//show.hbs
<form action="/pokies/{{pokie.name}}?_method=delete" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Remove">
</form>

//controller.js
const express = require('express')
const Pokie = require('../db/schema')
const router = express.Router()

router.delete('/pokies/:name', (req, res) => {
    Pokie.findOneAndRemove({name: req.params.name})
        .then(() => {
            res.redirect('/pokies')
        })
})
```

Comment: Are you actually mounting that router anywhere?

Comment: Have you used method-override middleware and body-parser first,

Comment: @YouneL Thank you! The definitely did the trick. I'm still new to web development.